# If PHP password_hash() creates a random salt and does not store it, how does it then retrieve the password?

Tags: php, bcrypt

If PHP password_hash() creates a random salt and does not store it, how does it then retrieve the right password?

Isn't the hash supposed to be distorted by the salt which is not stored in this implementation?

I don't really understand this from here (http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/password.c#111):

```
271/* {{{ proto boolean password_make_salt(string password, string hash)
272Verify a hash created using crypt() or password_hash() */
273PHP_FUNCTION(password_verify)
274{
275    int status = 0, i;
276    int password_len, hash_len;
277    char *ret, *password, *hash;
278
279    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &password, &password_len, &hash, &hash_len) == FAILURE) {
280        RETURN_FALSE;
281    }
282    if (php_crypt(password, password_len, hash, hash_len, &ret) == FAILURE) {
283        RETURN_FALSE;
284    }
285
286    if (strlen(ret) != hash_len || hash_len < 13) {
287        efree(ret);
288        RETURN_FALSE;
289    }
290
291    /* We're using this method instead of == in order to provide
292     * resistence towards timing attacks. This is a constant time
293     * equality check that will always check every byte of both
294     * values. */
295    for (i = 0; i < hash_len; i++) {
296        status |= (ret[i] ^ hash[i]);
297    }
298
299    efree(ret);
300
301    RETURN_BOOL(status == 0);
302
303}
304/* }}}
```

Comment: It does store it.... it stores it as part of the returned hash value, it also stores the algorithm used, and the cost argument

Comment: See the duplicate. Since `password_hash` is just a wrapper around `crypt`, the explanation applies.

Comment: If this table was say printed by a malicious user and she knew I used password_hash(),the malicious break down column into word hash and salt. Sow that he has the salt he needs to for a password, he then has to for each password run the entire gamut of possibilities along with the salt to obtain the crack for a specific user. Because it is random, it slows him down a lot because he needs to do this search for each and every user since they all have different salts. I think I get it now?

Comment: If you're targeted you're screwed, but the population as a whole is hard to crack.

Comment: The only point of a salt is to make the hash unique, so two passwords don't hash to the same value. That prevents the pre-computation of rainbow tables, which forces an attacker to brute force each and every password individually, which is infeasible on todays hardware and would take years and years even for a single password, not to mention an entire database, if you're using a strong hash.